# Binding an array of objects to template containing google-map-marker elements

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have this `<dom-module>` with a property `locations` of type Array that get updated externally every once in a while:

```html
<dom-module id="my-map">
    <template>
        <google-map api-key="MY_API_KEY" id="map" libraries="visualization,geometry,drawing">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{locations}}" as="user">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{user.trace}}">
                    <google-map-marker latitude="{{item.latitude}}" longitude="{{item.longitude}}">
                    </google-map-marker>
                </template>
            </template>
        </google-map>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is : 'my-map',
    properties : {
        locations : {
            type : Array,
            value : [],
            observer : '_locationsChanged'
        }
    },
    ready : function(){
        var self = this;
        this.map = this.querySelector('google-map');
        this.map.addEventListener('google-map-ready',function(){
            // some styling happening here.
        });
    },
    _locationsChanged : function(newLocations, oldLocations){
        // this fires correctly! ...
    }
});
</script>
```

In another module, I send an AJAX request to retrieve the data to be shown as markers on the map. 
Once the request finishes, I update the locations property and the `_locationsChanged` callback fires perfectly fine.

The data in that case looks something like this:

```json
[  
    {  
      "_id":"someID1",
      "trace":[  
        {  
          "latitude":55.629215086862,
          "longitude":10.640099246067,
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "_id":"someID2",
      "trace":[  
        {  
          "latitude":50.14743798944287,
          "longitude":18.52913082363756,
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Something weird happens.

Whenever locations is an empty array, the `newLocations` are bound without problems to the `<template dom-repeat="{{locations}}">` element. However, if the map already had shown a couple of markers, the old `<google-map-marker>` objects are still there, the new ones are simply *added*.
So if I do this in the dev console `document.querySelectorAll('google-map-marker')` after an update to `locations`, I see both the `newLocations` **and** the `oldLocations`.

To test that the data-binding works correctly if applied outside the `<google-map>` element, I added a similar template. Here, everything works perfectly as expected:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{locations}}" as="user">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>{{user._id}}</span>
            <ul>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{user.trace}}" as="trace">
                    <li><span>Lat:</span><span>{{trace.latitude}}</span></li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Here's what **did not** help so far:

- Calling `clear()` on the GoogleMap object.
- creating a second property that is bound to the dom-repeat template, but accessed [this way](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation):

```js
    this.splice('_locations',0,this._locations.length);
    newLocations.forEach(function(location){
        self.push('_locations',location);
    });
```

- using one-way data binding.
- manually removing DOM nodes via `googleMap.removeChild(marker)` and adding them. Okay, this actually worked to some degree but isn't the whole point of data-binding that you don't have to do this?

So, to sum up: The `<template is="dom-repeat">` inside the google map **does not get notified correctly** about changes to the `locations` property. 
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or if data-binding does not work inside a `<google-map>` element? Am I mixing things up with shady / shadow DOM? Am I using the dom-repeat thing incorrectly? Am I going to lose my mind?  I'll appreciate any hint towards a solution. Thanks!

Comment: You can assign an observer in dom-repeat as well. Read documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it makes a difference for your specific problem but default values for arrays and objects should be specified in this [format](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values) (see **value** attribute) :

```
 properties : {
        locations : {
            type : Array,
            value : function() { return [];},
            observer : '_locationsChanged'
        }
    },
```

I also think you have to call `clear()` on the `google-map` element because the `_updateMarkers()` function does not do this for you (see [here](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map.html#L380))